# ScrollView Effect

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-widget

I have a `Listview` in my application.  I have set the `ScrollView` to my `LinearLayout`.  Now I want to set the `ScrollView` visible only while I am scrolling. If i am not scrolling, then it should not be shown.

Any idea for this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `View myView`,

`myView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollbarFadingEnabled%28boolean%29

Comment: Hey. . .  i want to set this Property in my xml file. . .  is it Possible  ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the scroll bar size to be 0, this is part of the View flags so that's why you don't find it in the ScrollView docs.

[View | Android Dev](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3ascrollbarSize)

so either set it in layout.xml:

```
android:scrollbarSize="1px"
```

Comment: But i want to show it only while i m scrolling it. . .  is that code works ??

Comment: Aleadam's answer is what you want if you want it to be visible when scrolling.  I set mine to 0px in the XML file, but this requires a static ScrollView.